# Нужно ли двоеточие после словосочетания «дурная привычка»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

Нужно ли, например, тире или двоеточие после «дурная привычка»?

> Просто дурная привычка спрашивать не думая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Просто **дурная** привычка – **спрашивать не думая**.*

В этом случае следует поставить тире.

**Пояснение**

Сочетание "привычка (какая?) спрашивать" возможно и без постановки знаков, это связь примыкание, инфинитив является несогласованным определением.

Но в данном случае тире необходимо, так как распространенный оборот имеет **пояснительное значение**, что соответствует правилу Розенталя: Несогласованные определения (пункт3) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

3. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова **а именно**, отделяется посредством **тире:** …Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с **единственным** желанием — сделать добро! (Ч.); Но прекрасен **данный** жребий — просиять и умереть (Бр.);

Comment: Sharon, а зачем вы выделили согласованные определения? У Розенталя выделены инфинитивы, о которых идёт речь. // Для объяснения, как мне кажется, очень не хватает контекста, ведь ***привычка*** и ***спрашивать не думая*** могут быть сказуемым и подлежащим. Не?

Comment: Я это предложения поняла так: (Это) просто дурная привычка – спрашивать не думая. Причем поняла эту фразу как извинение (некто говорит это о себе). Этот вариант решается по Розенталю (обособление несогласованного определения), и в этом случае согласованное определение нужно. Обычно именно оно требует пояснения (единственное желание, данный жребий).  Вариант с подлежащим и сказуемым я не рассматривала, хотя в принципе он возможен. Но здесь мешает частица "просто" в начале предложения, ей там (перед подлежащим) вроде бы не место.

Comment: О необходимости согласованного определения в том пункте не сказано, и есть пример без него: *С батареи получен приказ — не отнимать трубку от уха...* // Я тоже понял предложение с отстуствующим "это", и у меня подлежащее – "спрашивать", сказуемое – "привычка", а "просто" никак не влияет.  *Спрашивать не думая – это просто дурная привычка.*

Comment: (1) Был получен приказ не вешать трубку. Есть тире? Нет тире.  А при наличии определения тире становится обязательным.  Розенталь просто забыл об этом сказать, а иначе что пояснять-то? (2) А зачем перестановку делаете? Работать надо с заданным предложением. (3) Автор вообще хотел двоеточие поставить, вряд ли это подходящий знак между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: Перестановка просто показыает прямой порядок. Ладно, пока!

Comment: Если был обратный порядок, значит, он и  был нужен. Ладно, пока!

Comment: В любом случае вам плюс.